# Google App Engine Sockets API

Tags: java, google-app-engine

For the new Sockets API, what does this mean:

```
Port 25 (SMTP) is blocked; you can still use authenticated SMTP on the submission port 587.
```

What does this mean for *sending* and *receiving* emails from within a GAE app?

**Update:**

Searching around here at SO, I find that even with SMTP Port 25 blocked it is still possible that the Outbound sockets to talk to external SMTP (Non-Google)

Comment: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/888/Checking+your+outgoing+mail+server+%28Is+Port+25+blocked%3F%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that they are not allowing you to use the Sockets API to send mails around. At least not on port 25. 
There is api for sending emails from App Engine. So you don't have to use the Sockets API.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview

Doesn't that help you better? If not can you give a little bit more context to your problem?

Comment: I need to send email, using a non-Gmail SMTP

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for you to send emails using App Engine.  One is to use the mail API (which has some limits) and the other is to use the socket API.  The socket API however will not allow you to send email on port 25. Even though port 25 is the SMTP port and if you want to send an email to most SMTP servers you'd need to use that port, many servers are set up to use a submission port (465) for email clients to send email.  These ports will require authentication.  It's usually the port that you'd configure your email client to use (e.g. thunderbird) but it can be used by any type of client, including your app-engine app.  Hence, if you have a gmail account and want to use smtp instead of the app engine mail api, you can send your email through the gmail smtp servers.  For that matter any smtp server that will authenticate you on a port other than 25 will work.